# Incompatible types on method

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

class StandardDeviation{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    double in=kb.nextDouble();
    while(in!=-1){
        numbers.add(kb.nextDouble()); 
    }
    double avg = getAvg(numbers);
    double stdD = getD(avg,numbers);// tells me these are incompatible types
    System.out.printf("%f\n",stdD);
  }

  public static double getAvg(ArrayList<Double> numbers){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (Double num : numbers){
        sum+= num;
    }
    return sum/numbers.size();
  }

  public static void getD(double avg, ArrayList<Double> numbers){
    ArrayList<Double> newSet = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        newSet.add(Math.pow(numbers.get(i)-avg,2));
    }
    double total = 0.0;
    for (Double num : newSet){
        total += num;
    }
    double mean =(total/numbers.size());
    return Math.sqrt(mean);
  }
}
```

Im so tired and I got this far into this exercise, I'm not even sure if it prints out the correct answer but right now its telling me
        double stdD = getD(avg,numbers);
that there are incompatible types, not sure what is incompatible
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getD` is void, it doesn't return a value.  It's currently

```
public static void getD(double avg, ArrayList<Double> numbers){
```

but it should probably be

```
public static double getD(double avg, ArrayList<Double> numbers){
```

Comment: Huh. I thought it was an error to return a value from a void.

Comment: @Tharwen well ok there were two errors. 1st he tried to write a void into a variable and secondly try to return a value in a void method. but since he wanted to write a value in the double variable the actual error was the void return type, not the return in a void method.

Comment: @tagtraeumer I understand your answer, I just meant that I wouldn't have expected a void that returned a value to compile in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

```
Your method is not returning anything. method return type is void and you are assigning that into double. that's why you are getting an error. Your method declaration should be like this - 

public static double getD(double avg, ArrayList<Double> numbers)
```